# Regularly Sent API Requests from a JSF/EJB Application

Tags: jsf, ejb, cdi, facescontext

I have some API requests generated on a schedule.

I can't use JSF CDI beans as they do not have a schedule or timer function.

I cant use a scheduler in stateless EJB as it can not access FacesContext which I use to generate API request.

How can I have periodic API requests generated from a JSF / EJB application.

Comment: FacesContext is just a facade. What exactly do you need from it? It can surely be obtained or prepared other way.

Comment: I want to generate API requests from a JSF + EJB application. If there is a way to send them without FacesContext, that would be better, but I could not find a method to send API request from EJBs.

Comment: Can you try "JAX-RS client" or "Apache HttpClient"